# Java source Hashtable

Tags: java, garbage-collection, hashtable

I don't known how to search this question, so I asked a question.
Java version 1.7.0_80_x86
The `remove` method in `java.util.Hashtable`;
I see that the value attribute of node `e` is set to `null`;
However, `e.next` is not set to null;
So if `e.next` is not null, will node `e` not be reclaimed by gc?
Method source code:

```
/**
 * Removes the key (and its corresponding value) from this
 * hashtable. This method does nothing if the key is not in the hashtable.
 *
 * @param   key   the key that needs to be removed
 * @return  the value to which the key had been mapped in this hashtable,
 *          or <code>null</code> if the key did not have a mapping
 * @throws  NullPointerException  if the key is <code>null</code>
 */
public synchronized V remove(Object key) {
    Entry tab[] = table;
    int hash = hash(key);
    int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
    for (Entry<K,V> e = tab[index], prev = null ; e != null ; prev = e, e = e.next) {
        if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)) {
            modCount++;
            if (prev != null) {
                prev.next = e.next;
            } else {
                tab[index] = e.next;
            }
            count--;
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = null;
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why would value of `e.next` prevent GC of `e`? Since `e` itself is unreachable, `e` *will* be reclaimed.

Comment: Why not? `e`is not longer reachable by any code. Yes, `e.next` can still be reached (and will not be garbage collected, it's still in table). But you want `e` to be garbage collected.

Comment: @Andreas I seem to be in the wrong place. Isn't `e.next` holding another object? Can it be recycled?

Comment: Since nothing reference to it anymore, it will be reclaimed by GC, **e.next** holding reference to another object, not holding another object

Comment: @Michael Yes, `e.next` *may* hold another object, that hasn't (and shouldn't be) removed from the Hashtable. It is `e` itself that is no longer used and will be reclaimed, not `e.next`. --- Also note that since `e` will be reclaimed, `e.value = null` is redundant, but it a (misguided?) attempt to help the garbage collector.

Comment: Just so you are really clear, most of the *will be reclaimed/garbage collected* here really means *can be reclaimed/garbage collected*.

Comment: **a -> b -> c**, so **a.next = b** and **b.next = c**, remove **b**, so **a.next = b.next** mean **a.next = c**, nothing can reach **b** anymore, so **b** will be reclaimed by GC

Comment: I see the problem. Thank you~ Thank you~ Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Every object tree must have one or more root objects. As long as application can reach these roots they are considered as live object if application cant reach these roots then they are collected by garbage collector. So answer to your question is yes "e" will be garbage collected by GC. But "e.next" may or may not be garbage collected by GC. If their is a reference to "e.next" (other than "e") then it will not else it will garbage collected by GC.